# Class based View: redirect if logged in, else render template

Tags: django, django-views

How can I achieve this in the most generic way? I thought of overriding `get()`, but I'd have to override too many methods. Also tried with `as_view()` but I can't access the request from there.

I also tried adding a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url" />` in the template, but I throught that was not the best approach.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I doubt you want to override `as_view` unless you are doing something exceptionally odd. It returns a function that is used as the view. The function it returns does little more than call `dispatch`.

You can override the specific method you want. eg `get`, alternatively, if you want to override all methods (`get`, `post`, etc), you should override `dispatch`.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class MyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'my_app/my_template.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('my-other-view')
        return super(MyView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

[CCBV.co.uk](http://ccbv.co.uk) is a good reference for learning django's class based views. *Disclaimer: I built it.*

Answer (score 0):

I'll copy @meshy's answer with a little edit, `request.user.is_authenticated` is a bool and you cannot call it. Change just this bit in `dispatch` method:

```
...

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        ....
```

Comment: Usually for such a minor edit, you comment on the original answer, and do not create a new answer. Once you get 50 reputation point you can [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I've edited my answer now.